# How to correctly install moongl via command prompt?

Tags: opengl, cmd, makefile, lua

I'm unable to install moongl after cloning it from github. I start to struggle at "moongl$ make" because I keep getting the error:

```
'moongl$' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I've tried changing the command to just "moongl" but nothing I do seems to work.

Folder structure:
moongl -> moongl -> make.lua

```
$ git clone https://github.com/stetre/moongl
$ cd moongl
moongl$ make
moongl$ make install # or 'sudo make install' (Ubuntu)
```

I'm suppose to be able to build moongl according to this: https://github.com/stetre/moongl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "moongl$" part in "moongl$ make" is not part of the actual command. It is the indicator of the terminal specifying in which folder you are currently residing.

The command you want to use is "make". However, this is command based on Linux and you are clearly using this on Windows. What you should do, is install [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/getting_started) and run "c:/MinGW/bin/make.exe" in the moongl folder.